# Cancel subscription using CyberSource

Tags: angular, payment-gateway, cybersource

I am using CyberSource Payment getway. In this we wan't cancel subscription I read many document for this, they provide sample code of key like which key we should pas for cancellation but they are not mention which api we should call. This is Documentation link :-

http://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/Recurring_Billing/SO_API/Recurring_Billing_SO_API.pdf

This is, How do I Cancel a Subscription via Code:-

Set1 the paySubscriptionUpdateService_run service field to true.
Step 2 Include the following fields in the request:

```
     merchantID
     merchantReferenceCode
     recurringSubscriptionInfo_status—set to cancel.
     recurringSubscriptionInfo_subscriptionID
```

Please can you clear which api we should call for that.

Answer (score -1):

You will need a CyberSource client. You can build your own like described in the [SOAP Toolkits document](http://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/SOAP_Toolkits/SOAP_toolkits.pdf) or you can use one of the pre-built clients described [here](https://www.cybersource.com/developers/getting_started/integration_methods/simple_order_api/#APIs+%26+Integration). Both these documents contain the endpoints to send your message to.

Once that is done you can send the cancel subscription message as you described.